# How does Sublime open file with cmd+click on its path in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, text-editor, sublimetext

1. For example:

   ```
   $ ls -lsa
   4 -rw-r--r--    1 denis     404 Jul 16 18:36 pgadmin.log
   ```
2. cmd+click on pgadmin.log
3. Sublime opens pgadmin.log (if path is 'pgadmin.log:12', it opens it and sets cursor to 12th line).

How to change the App, which opens the file?

Comment: Why don't you add this as an answer below and (after the grace period) accept it?

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. :(

Comment: I've checked my suggestion and it worked: if you try to open a file in Finder, this file will be opened with default Application, assigned to its extension. So, if you change default App for this file, you'll get it while opening file from Terminal by click.

Comment: You got enough reputation now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked my suggestion and it worked: if you try to open a file in Finder, this file will be opened with default Application, assigned to its extension. So, if you change default App for this file, you'll get it while opening file from Terminal by click.